# Canvas in Bootstrap modal is giving me wrong mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas, mouse

Im trying to figure out what im dooing wrong. I have a hmtl5 canvas inside a bootstrap modal. The canvas is a selecting game where you select objects inside the canvas and manipulate them.

Unfortunately it works allright in the center of the 600x600px Canvas but im getting a wierd offset when im trying to get the coordinates in the corner of the picture. The offset is getting bigger as you get closer to the corners

Here's my code.

Thank you very much in advance!

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;


    let imgObj = new Image();

    imgObj.onload = function() {
        let w = canvas.width;
        let nw = imgObj.naturalWidth; //1350
        let nh = imgObj.naturalHeight; //900
        console.log(nw);
        console.log(nh);
        let aspect = nw / nh;
        let h = w / aspect;
        console.log('height', h)
        canvas.height = h;
        soldTilesDisplay.textContent = totalTiles-soldTiles;
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, w, h);
        
        rectangulize_with_IDs();
        fillarraywithrandomTiles(soldTiles);

        //greyscaleOriginal();
        //ctx.drawImage(imgObj, dx, dy);
        //ctx.drawImage(imgObj, dx, dy, dw, dh);
        //ctx.drawImage(imgObj, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
    };

    function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
        let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        let x = event.clientX - Math.floor(rect.left);
        let y = event.clientY - Math.floor(rect.top); 
        
        storePixelArray(x, y);  // originale "Store in Array funktion"
        store_rect(x,y);
        clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
        console.log("Exact Coordinates: X: " + x,
            " Y: " + y, "CLick Counter: "+ clickcounter);
        }
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <!-- Bootstrap Modal here!-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">

            <!-- Bootstrap Modal here!-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3>WIN!</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <canvas id="canvas" style="background-image: url('/images/Berge.png')"></canvas>


                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center">

                                        <div class="card text-center" style="width: 30rem;">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title" id="Punktestand"> Card Title
                                                    Score:
                                                </h5>
                                                <p class="card-text" id="paragraphImModal">With supporting
                                                    text below as a natural
                                                    lead-in to additional content.</p>


                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="usePointsPixelButton">
                                                    Select Pixel first</button>
                                                <br>

                                                <h5 class="selectedPixelAmount" id="AmountOfPixels"> </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after running into the same Issue.
It is because the class .modal-dialog and every subclass under it has a relative positioning. just set the positioning to unset and you get the correct coordinates.

in my case i had to change following classes:

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: unset;
}

.modal-content {
    position: unset;
}

.modal-body {
    position: unset;
}

.alert {
    position: unset;
}
```

If you want you can do css stuff like "just change the position of modal-body inside modal dialog" so you dont mess up anything else :)